# Is ajax dependent on jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have googled about this but didn't found much about.So if someone could elaborate about this will be a great help.

Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Comment: no is native to javascript

Comment: No its not dependent on jquery

Comment: no, ajax is a technique and jquery is a js library

Comment: then why can't we run without the jquery.js or jquery.min.js

Comment: AJAX = asynchronous JavaScript and XML

Comment: Nothing is dependent on jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

No

Ajax means Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. With ajax you can create rich web application where new data is displayed, after user interaction without loading an entirely new html document.

You can create applications that use ajax techniques with XHR, the new fetch API or jQuery.ajax to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

No. AJAX is built-in into browsers as `XMLHttpRequest`. However, different browsers have different implementations (each with it's own quirks) of `XMLHttpRequest`'s implementation and `jQuery.ajax` bridges those differences by exposing unifying API to developers.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is not dependent on jQuery. jQuery is the framework of javascript. You can also use ajax using jQuery in a simplified format.

```
$.ajax({
    url : '', // Your url to be requested
    data : {
    }, // Data to be passed to the server
    dataType : 'JSON'
});
```

When you are using the above $.ajax inherit the method defined in jquery library.

If you want to use without including jquery library you have to use like below. this does not require jquery library

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.asp",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

reference: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: check my updated code, instead of creating the object in above example (xmlhttp) you are using $.ajax , thats why you have to include jquery library, if you use second method you need not to include

Comment: then why we have to use jquery.js library for that

Comment: @prasadkadam check my updated code, instead of creating the object in above example (xmlhttp) you are using $.ajax , thats why you have to include jquery library, if you use second method you need not to include